# Nodemailer Connection timeout at SMTPConnection._formatError

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, vue.js, nodemailer

Our nodemailer smtp configuration was:

`host: example.host
port: 25
pool: true
maxConnections: 2
authMethod: 'PLAIN'
      auth:
        user: 'username'
        pass: 'pass'`

It was throwing me an error, Connection timeout at SMTPConnection._formatError sometimes. Not every single request.

Answer (score 0):

My colleague figured out that it was pooling connection kept open when we should have been closing it.

Changed configuration to:

`host: example.host
authMethod: 'PLAIN'
      auth:
        user: 'username'
        pass: 'pass'`

and killed pooling since the amount of email is limited.